# How get Activity from a view?

Tags: android, android-activity, classcastexception

I have a extended class .i need activity.

```
public class RequestRecord extends RelativeLayout
{
    public RequestRecord(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        ContextWrapper ctx = ((ContextWrapper) getContext());
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) ((Activity) 
                                   ctx).findViewById(R.id.myReqList_scroll);
   }
}
```

Exception:   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl cannot be cast to android.content.ContextWrapper

help me?

Comment: Have the activity push the `ScrollView` into the `RequestRecord` by calling a setter method. Or, have the `ScrollView` be part of `RequestRecord`. Or, possibly, do not create a custom subclass of `RelativeLayout`, as what you seem to be doing is a bit unusual in Android app development.

Comment: Huh? Extending containers and usage of "compound views" is totally common AFAIK. although you generally do not access the external Activity like this, especially not its view hierarchy directly; that is true.

Answer (score 2):

This used to always work for me, when I obtained the view from inflation rather than with some tricky manual instantiation (for example, it won't work if the view is created with application context):

```
@NonNull
public static <T extends Activity> T findActivity(@NonNull Context context) {
    if(context == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Context cannot be null!");
    }
    if(context instanceof Activity) {
        // noinspection unchecked
        return (T) context;
    } else {
        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = (ContextWrapper) context;
        Context baseContext = contextWrapper.getBaseContext();
        if(baseContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity was not found as base context of view!");
        }
        return findActivity(baseContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What ever context object is being returned by `getContext()` doesn't extend `ContextWrapper`. Further, View **shouldn't** access their parent `Activity`, nor should they even know about an `Activity`. Why would a view need to be aware of another view in such manner. The proper way, if you want to access a sibling view, would be to get your parent `ViewGroup` and iterate over it's children. Note, while in the constructor, you don't have a parent `View` yet so calling `getParent()` will return `null`. You need to do that work during any of the on* methods such as: `onMeasure(...)`, `onLayout()`, `onSizeChanged` and `onSizeChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

If ScrollView **myReqList_scroll** is inside your **RequestRecord**, you can call like this

```
public class RequestRecord extends RelativeLayout
{
    public RequestRecord(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myReqList_scroll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun getActivity(context: Context?): Activity? {
    return if (context is Activity) context
    else if (context is ContextThemeWrapper) getActivity(context.getBaseContext())
    else if (context?.javaClass?.simpleName?.contentEquals("ContextImpl") ?: false)
        getActivity(getOuterContext(context))
    else {
        while (context is ContextWrapper) {
            if (context is Activity)
                context
            else
                getActivity(context.getBaseContext())
        }
        null
    }
}

fun getOuterContext(context: Context?): Context? {
    try {
        val f: Field? = context?.javaClass?.getDeclaredField("mOuterContext")
        f?.setAccessible(true)
        return if (f == null) null else (f.get(context) as Context?)
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}
```